# Javassist - CannotCompileException: No such Class : System.out

Tags: java, system, javassist

I'm trying to use javassist in order to add a System.out.println into an existing class's Methods, using this code -

```
....
ClassPool pool = new ClassPool();

        try {
            pool.appendClassPath(targetPath);
            CtClass cc = pool.get("model.Ball");

            CtMethod[] cm = cc.getDeclaredMethods();

            for (CtMethod m : cm) {

                String temp = m.getName();
                m.insertBefore("{ System.out.println(\"Executed Method \" + temp); }");                 
            }
```

However I keep Receiving this Stacktrace:

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: System.out
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:774)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:734)
    at reverseEngineer.dynamicparser.DynamicAnalyser.methodInformation(DynamicAnalyser.java:77)
    at reverseEngineer.dynamicparser.DynamicAnalyser.loadClass(DynamicAnalyser.java:61)
    at reverseEngineer.ModelParser.parseDynamic(ModelParser.java:77)
    at reverseEngineer.ModelParser.parseTarget(ModelParser.java:44)
    at reverseEngineer.Driver.main(Driver.java:30)
Caused by: compile error: no such class: System.out
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:468)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:412)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByJvmName(MemberResolver.java:319)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:678)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:569)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:754)
    ... 6 more
```

I've tried testing with

```
  m.insertBefore("{ int x = 1; }");
```

Which works perfectly fine - Changing the System.out.println() to System.getcurrenttimemillis() returns the same stacktrace only with "no such class: System"

Comment: "{ System.out.println(\"Executed Method \" + temp); }" will not work. you need something like"{ System.out.println(\"Executed Method " + temp + "\"); }"

Comment: try `java.lang.System`

Answer (score 0):

You create the ClassPool like:

```
ClassPool pool = new ClassPool();
```

Which creates an empty ClassPool, not even the default Java classes from rt.jar. So there is no System class defined and compilation failes.

By using:

```
ClassPool pool = new ClassPool(true);
```

You will get a ClassPool with the stuff from the classPath and system jars already added. System class is found and it compiles.